# Could someone explain the Kevin Bacon joke in Guardians of the Galaxy?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, guardians-of-the-galaxy

There was a moment in the movie when Starlord told a joke about Kevin Bacon to convince his partner to dance. My fellow moviegoers laughed heartily but I, being a non-US person, missed the joke completely. Could anyone explain the joke, starting with who Kevin Bacon is in real life?

Comment: you just need to watch the movie Footloose to understand.

Comment: @BenPlont Agreed. Footloose was a popular and important movie to American teenagers when it came out. The actor Kevin Bacon played the hero, who transformed a small town through his dancing and through getting other teenagers to dance (and rebel against their controlling parents).

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This is just a funny reference to the movie [*Footloose*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0087277/), a dancing movie from the 80s starring the actor [*Kevin Bacon*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kevin_Bacon) in the lead role. In fact *Peter* does summarize the story of this movie quite accurately:

> Well, on my planet, we have a legend about people like you. It's called Footloose. And in it, a great hero, named Kevin Bacon, teaches an entire city full of people with sticks up their butts that, dancing, well, is the greatest thing there is.

Seeing that the movie was released in 1984, it should've been one of the most recent movies *Peter* watched as a child before his abduction and he is indeed quite into dancing. And seeing that the story of the movie was about convincing people to dance, it fits the bill pretty well as a parable for his and *Gamora*'s current situation.

<sub>As a side note, after this scene I waited for an actual *Footloose* homage later in the movie, which unfortunately didn't come, but if any movie could have included that it would have been *Guardians of the Galaxy*, I guess.</sub>

Comment: Well, Gamora does remark "We're just like Kevin Bacon!" nearing the end, but I suppose that's all you get.

Comment: @MrDoom Yeah, though I admit I didn't really get what she meant with this at all. Did she just mean *"we own them!"* or something similar? And while the music of the movie was more grounded in the 70s (as it was actually his mom's), I would have *loved* to hear *Footloose* in that movie.

Comment: I generally took it to mean that her interpretation of *Footloose* ended up as Kevin Bacon being a great warrior coming to save the people. It's quite possible we're both over analyzing what is meant to be a one-off funny remark.

Answer (score 1):

The laugh was more because she took his reference way too literally. "A stick up someone's butt" in this country refers to people who are way too strict or have no sense of humor. You don't have to see *Footloose* to get that he doesn't mean they really have sticks up their butts. Just like the joke "nothing goes over my head, I'm too quick".

Comment: Though, it seemed to have been the Kevin bacon part in particularly that asker was confused of and not so much the stick part.

Answer (score -3):

There is a game called Six Degrees of Kevin Bacon. You name an actor or actress in a movie and a co-star. Then you name that co-star and another actor or actress. You have six steps to get the correlation from initial actor to Kevin Bacon. The joke in the US is that Kevin Bacon is in EVERYTHING. Notice Peter Quill didn't say "Ren", the character name in Footloose...but Kevin Bacon, the name of the actor who played him. So for me, it was funny because it was another example of Kevin Bacon is in everything (sure, he wasn't really in Guardians, but they talked about him, so in a way he was.) Then when she says "We're just like Kevin Bacon," it's funny to me because she is almost saying Kevin Bacon is god-like.

Comment: I think you may be right that Kevin Bacon was specifically mentioned because of the game.   But that's a tough one to prove.  The footloose reference works with or without the Kevin Bacon game.

Answer (score -6):

I read all of these answers and I believe there is SOMETHING MAJOR related to Kevin Bacon Footloose references in the MCU. Previously mentioned in this thread are the lines from GOTG film but this is also referenced by Mantis in Avengers Infinity War, Thor says that two stones are with the Avengers, Earths mightiest heroes, Mantis replies like Kevin Bacon. Most likely a film Mantis never saw but Mantis makes the connection Earth, Quills worlds', mightiest hero is from the Footloose story. SO HERE IT IS:  Sebastian Shaw is portrayed by actor Kevin Bacon in X Men First Class with Fassbenders Magneto, is evidence of different timeline, where the actors and the brands are not the same as ours. The Avengers from our Earth and Quill from our Earth will reference our culutral and pop memories as we remember them. SO Fassbenders Magneto future 80s babies wont get a Footloose starring Kevin Bacon, A paradox of sorts. My theory is every pop reference by Tony or Peter or anyone really, are part of this paradoxical idea that some characters will reference pop culture accurately and others innaccurately to display a "Mandela Effect" or consequence of altering the Multiverse in the MCU.

Comment: Welcome to Movies.SE! I'm afraid I'm not quite following you. Are you saying that *Footloose* doesn't exist in the MCU because Kevin Bacon happened to star in a film that isn't in the MCU?

Comment: Actually Footloose doesnt exist in the XMen First Class (20Fox). Footloose exists in the MCU.

Comment: Also Fassbenders Magneto is in the 60's and never saw 80s films like Flash Gordon and Footloose like their MCU counterparts. As the 20Fox XMen make thier way into the MCU this will be part of the story, which characters accuratley reference our pop culture and those that do not from the multiverse.

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/MovieDetails/comments/b2yl8j/spiderman_into_the_spiderverse_the_coca_cola/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

Comment: Also watch this clip from Last Action Hero https://youtu.be/G6PBhdM9Ftg

Comment: Also in the Blockbuster Video scene in Captain Marvel All of the films and actors are in line w our memory establishing she and Fury are from our Earth, compare this Blockbuster Video to Last Action Hero, you will realize this is a possibility and it is setup by Footloose talks.